# Can you upload an Xcode made Swift app to the Google Play store

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, google-play

Hey I want to know is there an way I can upload a app that I made in Xcode using the language of swift to the google play store? If so do I need to do anything special when submitting the application to the google play store. like use a api or cocoa pods to convert the apps IPA or something.

maybe using a IPA to APK converter

or how do the big apps do it like how Facebook has an app on the Apple Store and google play store 
I am using Xcode 9 swift 4 IOS 11

my app is sized up to all iPhone and iPad screen sizes.

This specific question hasn't been asked before, I don't think. It will probably get marked as off topic or something of that nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.ipa files are iOS files and .APK are Android files, there is no way to convert between the two. You can use third party SDK to convert same code for both like Xamarin.